# Glitch in the js flipcards - flipped

Tags: javascript, css

There are 3 cards at https://pretieyeinstitute.com.br/novo/ : Especialidades, Exames e Cirurgia. They are presenting a light glitch on mouseover. Does anyone knows what is causing this?

Comment: What JavaScript or JavaScript file do you use for the flip action? However, the issue occurs, as your javascript sets the .flipped class whenever you mouse-in or mouse-out on a card. So on mouse-enter the card gets smaller because of the flip effect which lead to an automatically mouse-out which triggers the un-flip action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue occurs, because on hover, the card flips. As the card itself decreases its width on flip action, the hover will be triggered again and the unflip is triggered.

Solution would be to add the hover effect on the parent of the card. Then hover will only triggered once - when the user hovers the cards parent element.

Change your cardflip JavaScript as the following should do the trick:

```
$('.card').parent().hover(function(){
    console.log('noob');
  $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```